# Overflow "Visible" and overflow "Scroll" for same style

Tags: css

Sorry if my question makes no sense. However in my case i need both to be active for the same style name. Is there any trick to achive this?

```
.side-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
          transform: translateX(-100%);
  height: 100%;
  height: calc(100% + 60px);
  height: -moz-calc(100%);
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-y: auto;
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-105%);
          transform: translateX(-105%);
          overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: ...it's either this one or that one. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is the required result?

Comment: As I said I need them both. The "Side-nav" div is set to fixed, and it has a div inside it that must be outside the parent div ".side-nav". Plus "side-nav" has also long content so i need it to be scroll.

Comment: So you need the div inside extend sideways, but also want the inner div to scroll vertically..?

Answer (score 1):

They can't both be active on the same element. "visible" means the content is visible beyond the bounds of the element. "scroll" (and auto) means the element will scroll to display content that goes outside the bounds of the element.

Comment: I'm guessing, but I think OP means same id or class but on two different elements. If not, then you are correct.

Comment: I have just uplaod my css code. As it is above, scroll not working, if change overflow > scroll than it works, however visible is also needed.

Comment: So, you do want both properties on the same element? Then @JimCote is correct and it's not possible. You'll need to rewrite your HTML/CSS to circumvent the issue.

Comment: yes, i do. and I know Jim Cote is right, but i thought there some one knows a trick...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in Bootstrap. Idk if that helps but you can just use the styles without bootstrap as well!

A horizontally scrollable "carousel" style row with no scrollbars

```css
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
* {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid overflow-scroll">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap overflow-visible">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="bg-primary">asdfafd
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 ">
        <div class="bg-light">asd
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="bg-light">asdfa
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="bg-light">asdfaf
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```